# The unmet dependencies are: * bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0), depended upon rails-4.2.11.3, unsatisfied by bundler-2.3.21

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am trying to set up my project but getting the error regarding bundler. I am using Rails 4.2.11.3
Please have a look at the image. [image]

Comment: Please avoid posting images of code. It's harder to read/is less accessible (e.g. screen readers or visually impaired people), and hinders search engines.

Comment: It's strongly preferred to copy+paste the code/log/error directly into your post, with appropriate formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a specific older version of `bundler` as follows:

```
bundle _1.17.3_
```

If this doesn't resolve to problem, I'd need more information about the `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` to understand how it's been "corrupted" into an invalid state of dependencies.